# adding accents (just acute) to .plist for Cyrillic vowels

Tags: keyboard, macos, plist

I have El Capitan 10.11.6 and I would like to be able to add acute marks above all vowels, lower and upper case.

I did this: `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true`

I could not get the `Option+e` to work, except in US keyboard.

I could not get Unicode keyboard to work on characters that, apparently, were not expected to have an acute on them.

So I edited the .plist - `System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/Keyboard-ru.plist` by adding a bunch of dictionaries - copies of the ones already there. I found the strings and caps strings from here:  https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/russian.htm

I just copied and pasted them into .plist using Xcode.

Most seem to work,

```
я́Я́
Е́е́
Ё́ё́
Э́э́
ы́Ы
У́у́
О́о́
Юю́
И́и́
```

but not all - above, those without the acute mark. (Yes, I know some shouldn't be in literature).

I see no difference between any of the other dictionary entries I added, again by just copying and pasting existing dictionaries and editing. I did restart the OSX.

Does anyone have any ideas?

PS Here is the contents of my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Э</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Э Э́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Э Э́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-A</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>А́ А</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>А́ А</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-a</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>а́ а</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>а́ а</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Е</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ё Е́ Ё́ Е</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ё Е́ Ё́ Е</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-О</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>О О́ Ә Ө</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>О О́ Ә Ө</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Г</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Г Ғ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Г Ғ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-К</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>К Қ Ҝ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>К Қ Ҝ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Н</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>center</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Н Ң Һ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Н Ң Һ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Я</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>center</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Я Я́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Я Я́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-У</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>У У́ Ұ Ү Ӯ Ў</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>У У́ Ұ Ү Ӯ Ў</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-И</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>И И́ Ӣ І</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>И И́ Ӣ І</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Й</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Й Й́ Ј</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Й Й́ Ј</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Ж</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ж Ӂ Җ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ж Ӂ Җ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Х</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Х Ҳ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Х Ҳ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Ч</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ч Ҷ Ҹ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ч Ҷ Ҹ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Ы́
&lt;/dict&gt;
&lt;/plist&gt;
</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ы́ Ы</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ы́ Ы</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Ю
&lt;/dict&gt;
&lt;/plist&gt;
 - 2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ю Ю́ Ю Ю́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ю Ю́ Ю Ю́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-Ь</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>Ь Ъ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>Ь Ъ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-е</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ё е́ ё́ е</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ё е́ ё́ е</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-о</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>о о́ ә ө</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>о о́ ә ө</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-г</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>г ғ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>г ғ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-к</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>к қ ҝ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>к қ ҝ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-н</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>н ң һ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>н ң һ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-у</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>у у́ ұ ү ӯ ў</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>у у́ ұ ү ӯ ў</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-и</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>и и́ ӣ і</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>и и́ ӣ і</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-й</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>й й́ ј</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>й й́ ј</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-ж</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ж ӂ җ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ж ӂ җ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-х</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>х ҳ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>х ҳ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-ч</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ч ҷ ҹ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ч ҷ ҹ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-ь</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ь ъ</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ь ъ</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-№</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string># №</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string># №</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-ы</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ы ы́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ы ы́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-э</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>э э́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>э э́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-я</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>я я́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>я я́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-ю</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>ю ю́</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>ю ю́</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Roman-Accent-#</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>right</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string># №</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string># №</string>
    </dict>
    <key>UI-ABC</key>
    <string>АБВ</string>
    <key>UI-AlternateCurrencySign-1</key>
    <string>$</string>
    <key>UI-AlternateCurrencySign-2</key>
    <string>€</string>
    <key>UI-AlternateCurrencySign-3</key>
    <string>£</string>
    <key>UI-Bold</key>
    <string>Жирный</string>
    <key>UI-Cancel</key>
    <string>Отменить</string>
    <key>UI-Copy</key>
    <string>Скопировать</string>
    <key>UI-Cut</key>
    <string>Вырезать</string>
    <key>UI-Done</key>
    <string>Готово</string>
    <key>UI-EmergencyCall</key>
    <string>Экстренный
вызов</string>
    <key>UI-Go</key>
    <string>Перейти</string>
    <key>UI-Italic</key>
    <string>Курсив</string>
    <key>UI-Join</key>
    <string>Подкл.</string>
    <key>UI-LanguageIndicator</key>
    <string>Русская</string>
    <key>UI-Next</key>
    <string>Далее</string>
    <key>UI-Numbers</key>
    <string>123</string>
    <key>UI-NumbersSymbols</key>
    <string>.?123</string>
    <key>UI-Paste</key>
    <string>Вставить</string>
    <key>UI-Pause</key>
    <string>пауза</string>
    <key>UI-Prediction</key>
    <string>Смахните вниз, чтобы закрыть</string>
    <key>UI-PrimaryCurrencySign</key>
    <string>₽</string>
    <key>UI-Redo</key>
    <string>Повторить</string>
    <key>UI-Return</key>
    <string>Ввод</string>
    <key>UI-Route</key>
    <string>Маршрут</string>
    <key>UI-Search</key>
    <string>Найти</string>
    <key>UI-Send</key>
    <string>Отправить</string>
    <key>UI-Space</key>
    <string>Пробел</string>
    <key>UI-TopLevelDomain</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Direction</key>
        <string>left</string>
        <key>Keycaps</key>
        <string>.com .ru .org .edu .рф</string>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <string>.com .ru .org .edu .рф</string>
    </dict>
    <key>UI-Underline</key>
    <string>Подчеркнутый</string>
    <key>UI-Undo</key>
    <string>Отменить</string>
    <key>UI-Wait</key>
    <string>ожидание</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a couple minutes work to create a custom keyboard with a key mapped to the combining acute, so you can add it to any character.  Which Cyrillic layout do you use, Russian or Russian Phonetic or some other?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/74vssudf98svya7/Russian%20-%20Phonetic%20Accents.keylayout) is phonetic one from a few years ago. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4ix7nvpy2tci8i/Russian%20Stress.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is a Russian version (with acute accent at Option ё).

Comment: much better!  I use 'Russian'

Comment: Does this replace my `/System/Library/DTDs/KeyboardLayout.dtd` or do I rename one? Thanks for the other via Dropbox too

Comment: You put the .keylayout file in Library/Keyboard Layouts, logout/login, then activate it in input source preferences.  It should be in the Others file, with the name Russian Stress.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to incorporate it, or a port, into X11/xkb on linux (Ubuntu or Debian), also using the Russian language? I may crosslink this answer to a new question in Unix/Linux or SuperUser....

Comment: @nate sorry, no.